# What's the term for when you replace "http://" with "myapp://" and have it open an external app?

Tags: html, url

Sites like Steam and Rhapsody use steam://xxx and rhapsody://xxx in web pages, and when you click on them they cause specific actions in their (locally installed) client applications.

I would like to do this for something I'm working on and I just don't know what the search term is so it's hard to get started. What is this called?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part before :// is called the **[URI Scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)**. Historically, they were often called the **protocol** as their primary purpose was to setup communication (e.g. HTTP, FTP, TCP). These days, URI Schemes are used for a variety of purposes (launching apps; [making payments](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki); [creating appointments](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791)).

[The Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Assigned_Numbers_Authority), best known for their role in allocating IP-addresses and managing the DNS root zones, also manages the [list of well-known URI Schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml).

Besides the well-known URI Schemes, most platforms allow developers to register their own schemes:

- [Windows - Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Android - Creating a custom intent](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Comment: No, “URI” refers to the *whole* thing, not just the part before `://` (that’s usually called the “p̶r̶o̶t̶o̶c̶o̶l” … err, what Philippe said: “scheme”).

Comment: The part before '://' is called the "scheme".

Comment: Not sure why you're getting the down votes, this is what I'm looking for. Thanks. I can't accept it for another few minutes.

Comment: @SidF Easily explained: look at the [first version of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34635743/1).